# Can I get the PartionKey and RowKey from TableOperation Retrieve operation?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

is there a way to get the PartitionKey and RowKey from the TableOperation parameter,

```
public override Task<TableResult> ExecuteAsync(TableOperation operation)
{
    switch (operation.OperationType)
    {
        case TableOperationType.Retrieve:
            //entityResult = Get<ITableEntity>(operation.PartitionKey, operation.RowKey);
            break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `operation.Entity.PartitionKey`?

Comment: @thepirat000 for this operation the `Entity` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Table Storage Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) introduced that:

**PartitionKey Property**:

Tables are partitioned to support load balancing across storage nodes. A table's entities are organized by partition. A partition is a consecutive range of entities possessing the same partition key value. The partition key is a unique identifier for the partition within a given table, specified by the `PartitionKey` property. The partition key forms the first part of an entity's primary key. The partition key may be a string value up to 1 KB in size.

You must include the `PartitionKey` property in every insert, update, and delete 
operation.

**RowKey Property**:

The second part of the primary key is the row key, specified by the `RowKey` property. The row key is a unique identifier for an entity within a given partition. Together the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` uniquely identify every entity within a table. 
The row key is a string value that may be up to 1 KB in size.

You must include the `RowKey` property in every insert, update, and delete operation.

**So we must include the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` property in every insert, update, and delete operation.**

`TableOperation.Retrieve` overloads three methods:
[image]

No matter which `Retrieve`, it all needs `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`:
[image]

You can't get the `PartionKey` and `RowKey` from TableOperation Retrieve operation.

When `TableOperation` is created, it shoud contains entity's  `PartionKey` and `RowKey`. 
For example:

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>("Smith", "Ben");
```

But in your method, `TableOperation operation` is a parameter, so the  `Entity` is `null`.

Hope this can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need using reflection, may be there is another option but reflection still simple implement

eg : var rowKey = GetField(tableOperationObject, "RowKey");

```
private string GetField(TableOperation operation, string field)
        {
            PropertyInfo highlightedItemProperty = operation.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic  | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == field);
            object value = highlightedItemProperty.GetValue(operation, null);
            
            return value?.ToString();
        }
```